# Wicket NonCachingImage Causing Page Constructor invoked twice

Tags: wicket

I have an `img` tag on a wicket page and I add image as following:

```
NonCachingImage banner = NonCachingImage(id, imageResource)
```

now i also add attributes like: `banner.add(new AttributeModifier("width",..`.

Now my page constructor is getting invoked twice. If for testing I also add

```
banner.add(new AttributeModifier("src", new Model<String>("test")
```

constructor would be invoked only once but the image would not be rendered. Please suggest me how can i render the correct image from `org.apache.wicket.Resource` and make the constructor getting invoked only once.

Would appreciate if you can direct me to specific examples.

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, <img> tags that are rendered with src="" (no url) the browser will submit a request to the current url in search of the image.  If your imageResource is resolving to an empty url path then this would occur.  Further, this would not happen if after creating the NonCachingImage you added an AttributeModifier which would override the generated src attribute with a value of "test" as the value would no longer be empty.